# ios - how a UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier generate by beginBackgroundTask

Tags: ios, background-process

When we call `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` it returns an `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier` as Task identifier.

In my app it starts from 7 and then 11 and etc.
my question is what is the basis of this number and why its not 1,2,3 ...
and why when I end task 7 the function will not return task ID 7 again?

I built again my app and saw task ID 7 again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> my question is what is the basis of this number

It doesn't matter. You shouldn't even be looking at the number. Your job is to receive the identifier from the runtime in `beginBackgroundTask...` and to pass it back to the runtime in `endBackgroundTask`. That is how the runtime knows they go together. End of story.